# saveAll hasMany doesn't work in CakePHP 2.0.6

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

See Gist for more details (Controller, Model, etc): https://gist.github.com/2017219

My problem is the following:
I have a normal form using the HTML Helper. With ajax, I add new inputs (file) to upload dynamic images.

**TipoImovel** (or in english, PropertyType)
**ImagemTipoImovel** (or ImagePropertyType)

When I run all the operations necessary to upload and validate the data, I get the following array (*saveAssociated its just a sample text*):

```
<?php 
// debug após sair do ImagemBehavior - responsável pelo upload

Array
(
    [TipoImovel] => Array
        (
            [empreendimento_id] => 2
            [tipo_id] => 1
            [chamada1] => <pre><span class="na">saveAssociated</span></pre>
            [chamada2] => <pre><span class="na">saveAssociated</span></pre>
            [chamada3] => <pre><span class="na">saveAssociated</span></pre>
            [descricao] => <pre><span class="na">saveAssociated</span></pre>
            [youtube_link] => saveAssociated
            [vimeo_embed] => saveAssociated
            [ativo] => 1
        )

    [ImagemTipoImovel] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [tipo_imovel_id] => 
                    [imagem] => 65d7adc2c7ed519e489789fc3eb60e8a.jpg
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [tipo_imovel_id] => 
                    [imagem] => f95bcebaecad405b2f7a50a2535d4c4b.jpg
                )

        )

)
```

After that I try to use the SaveAll, but is charged the following error:

```
Notice (8): Array to string conversion [CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php, line 964]

Database Error
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

SQL Query: INSERT INTO `imagem_tipo_imoveis` (`tipo_imovel_id`, `imagem`, `modified`, `created`) VALUES (23, Array, '2012-03-11 17:17:14', '2012-03-11 17:17:14')

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app/View/Errors/pdo_error.ctp

Stack Trace
#0 /home/patrick/workspace/.../cakephp/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php(436): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home/patrick/workspace/.../cakephp/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php(403): DboSource->_execute('INSERT INTO `im...', Array)
#2 /home/patrick/workspace/.../cakephp/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php(967): DboSource->execute('INSERT INTO `im...')
#3 /home/patrick/workspace/.../cakephp/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(1646): DboSource->create(Object(ImagemTipoImovel), Array, Array)
#4 /home/patrick/workspace/.../cakephp/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(1955): Model->save(Array, Array)
#5 /home/patrick/workspace/.../cakephp/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(2096): Model->saveMany(Array, Array)
#6 /home/patrick/workspace/.../cakephp/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(1908): Model->saveAssociated(Array, Array)
#7 /home/patrick/workspace/.../cakephp/app/Controller/TipoImoveisController.php(44): Model->saveAll(Array)
#8 [internal function]: TipoImoveisController->admin_add()
#9 /home/patrick/workspace/.../cakephp/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php(473): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(TipoImoveisController), Array)
#10 /home/patrick/workspace/.../cakephp/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(104): Controller->invokeAction(Object(CakeRequest))
#11 /home/patrick/workspace/.../cakephp/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(86): Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(TipoImoveisController), Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#12 /home/patrick/workspace/.../cakephp/app/webroot/index.php(96): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#13 {main}
```

Where is the problem?

**EDIT 12/03/2012 21:59h**

I did some tests and found the following:
beforeValidate **is not returning the name of the image**, ie, **the first he's trying to save for later beforeValidate run**, so he tries to save an array, only to then upload and return only the image name.

Now the question is: how to run something before saving, even in a hasMany relationship?

Comment: have you define the relationship in both model files ?

Comment: Why `[tipo_imovel_id] => ` is empty?

Comment: Please, I need the code of `INSERT INTO imagem_tipo_imoveis`, where is the save / saveAll to verify inconsistence?.

Comment: I believe that the upload has to be through the model `ImagemTipoImovel`, not `TipoImovel` as it is now. And set `dependent` attribute to true.

Comment: @SaiyamPatel Yes, its defined. And works fine when I make fix test.

Comment: @GabrielSantos As for tipo_imovel_id blank, it was just a test, if I put it or not, anyway, this will be completed during the save.

Comment: @GabrielSantos insert code: INSERT INTO `imagem_tipo_imoveis` (`imagem`, `tipo_imovel_id`, `modified`, `created`) VALUES (Array, 9, '2012-03-13 00:55:06', '2012-03-13 00:55:06')

Comment: @PauloRodrigues Yes, I believe you are correct, I'll try it now.

Comment: For updated question, you can execute something in `beforeSave` method even in a hasMany relationship, in any model. The inserts are made ​​separately in each model.

Comment: @PauloRodrigues You are correct, now everything is working the right way. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to set true in TipoImovel.php

```
'dependent' => true,
```

thanks

Comment: Just this doesnt work, but, when I put $actAs = 'ImagemBehavior' in ImagemTipoImovel, works great. Anyway thanks my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Try change `saveAll` to `saveAssociated`.

Comment: There was no difference, the solution was to instantiate the Behavior "ImagemTipoImovel" and not "TipoImovel." Anyway, thank you.