# Trying to save a hasMany array from multiple select

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to save a data from a multiple select. This data is relacioned where "Request" hasMany "Requestc". The foriegnKey is "request_id"

My Controller:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {

    $solicitacao = $this->Request->save($this->request->data['Request']);

    //Verifica se a request foi salva e se sim, salva quais as certidões foram pedidas na tabela requests_certidoes
    if(!empty($solicitacao)) {
        $this->request->data['Requestc']['request_id'] = $this->Request->id;
    //  debug($this->request->data);

        $this->Request->Requestc->saveAll($this->request->data);
    }
}
```

This is my data from `$this->request->data`:

```
array(
'Request' => array(
    'motivo' => 'Licitação',
    'nome_licitacao' => '',
    'data_pregao' => '',
    'nome_cliente' => '',
    'outros' => ''
),
'Requestc' => array(
    'caminho' => array(
        (int) 0 => '1',
        (int) 1 => '3'
    ),
    'request_id' => '60'
)
```

)

And that's the error:

Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

SQL Query: INSERT INTO `societario`.`requests_certidoes` (`caminho`, `request_id`) VALUES (Array, 62)

Thanks for all

Comment: possible duplicate of [saveAll hasMany doesn't work in CakePHP 2.0.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667015/saveall-hasmany-doesnt-work-in-cakephp-2-0-6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify the posted data so that it looks like this:

```
array(
    'Request' => array(
        'motivo' => 'Licitação',
        'nome_licitacao' => '',
        'data_pregao' => '',
        'nome_cliente' => '',
        'outros' => ''
    ),
    'Requestc' => array(
        0 => array(
            'caminho' => '1',
            // --> optionally add your request_id here
            //     if you're manually saving Requestc
            //     AFTER saving Request
        ),
        1 => array(
            'caminho' => '3',
        )
    )
)
```

If your relations are properly set-up, you probably don't have to add request_id;

```
$data = array(
    'Request' => $this->request->data['Request'],
    'Requestc' => array();
);

foreach($this->request->data['Requestc']['caminho'] as $val) {
    $data['Requestc'][] = array(
        'caminho' => $val,

        // Should NOT be nescessary when using the saveAssociated()
        // as below
        //'request_id' => $this->Request->id;
    );
}

// This should insert both the Request *and* the Requestc records
$this->Request->saveAssociated($data);
```

See the documentation: [Saving Related Model Data (hasOne, hasMany, belongsTo)](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-hasone-hasmany-belongsto)

However, if `Requestc.caminho` stores the `id` of `Certificates`, this seems to be a HABTM relation;  `Request --> HABTM --> Certificate`, in which case the join-table should be called `certificates_requests` and contain the columns `request_id` and `certificate_id`. See the [Model and Database Conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions)

Comment: Yes, my `Requestc.caminho` strores the `id` of `Certificates`!!!
After than I modify the table name and columns I need to change something in my code? I don't understand right...Thanks!!!

Comment: I changed the name of the coloumns and this is saving the `request_id` but is saving nothing in `certificate_id`. No errors apeears

Comment: Sorry for my late response (probably different time-zone), glad you got it working. Still may be worth to study how to use HABTM relations. Be aware though, **if your want to store additional data inside the `join` table  _itself_ .** (`certificates_requests`), to read this chapter: [hasMany through (The Join Model)](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through-the-join-model)