# CakePHP add multiple HABTM

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I got `List` and `Item`. I use `Javascript` to dynamically add `Item` `input` in order to add multiple of them to a single `List`. What is the `name` those input should have, or how does CakePHP create a HABTM relationship this way?

**EDIT:** So I read that the way to do this is to name my `Item` input like `Item.0.id`, `Item.1.id`, etc.

Since I'm using `JavaScript`, I don't see a way I could make the inputs using `$this->Form->input('Item.0.id');` dynamically when pressing a button, could I get some suggestions?

Comment: Maybe my question help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937068/trying-to-save-a-hasmany-array-from-multiple-select

Comment: I don't understand. Each Item added dynamically should be named Item.0.id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HABTM relationships are saved with a numerical array of IDs

So your inputs should be Item.0 and Item.1 with the IDs as the value.

To do this dynamically with javascript you would need to create the input yourself, which is not hard cakePHP just uses a name of "data[Model][key]"

Here's an example:

```
var index = 0;

$('buttonToClick').on('click', function(){
    var stringInput = '<input class="itemInput" name="data[Item][' + index + ']"/>';
    $('itemInput:last-child').after(stringInput);
});
```

Comment: Just realized that you are probably using a select list for this, so you would probably need to generate the first one with FormHelper then use jQuery's clone method to copy it, change the name attribute and then place it after the current one.